# What is the difference b/w Hurd and Minix?

Tags: minix, mach, microkernel

Knowing both are micro-kernels, what is the difference b/w Mach (on which Hurd is based on) and Minix. Are there any architectural differences? A little light over "what is L4" would be very helpful. I cannot find any documents covering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Mach is an implementation of the Mach microkernel. It is the default microkernel in the GNU Hurd operating system.

MINIX is a Unix-like computer operating system based on a microkernel architecture created by Andrew S. Tanenbaum for educational purposes.

I think that your question is incorrect. What the difference between Linux and FreeBSD? Each of this operating system implemented own system calls, application interfaces, etc.

L4 is a family of second-generation microkernels, generally used to implement Unix-like operating systems, but also used in a variety of other systems. L4, like its predecessor L3 was created by German computer scientist Jochen Liedtke as a response to the poor performance of earlier microkernel-based operating systems.

Read some links bellow:

- [Microkernel Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel)
- [GNU Mach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Mach)
- [Minix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minix)
- [L4 microkernel family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L4_microkernel_family)

Comment: This does not explain the difference between a Mach micro kernel and a Minix micro kernel.

Comment: Stop saying Minix was written for educational purposes. It's so discrediting.

Comment: But it was. Early versions of MINIX were created by Andrew S. Tanenbaum for educational purposes. Starting with MINIX 3, the primary aim of development shifted from education to the creation of a highly reliable and self-healing microkernel OS. MINIX is now developed as open-source software.